# gradle error in android studio while runnig flutter app

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to authenticate my login page activity with firebase. so, while doing that I got this Gradle error.

I refer to the below link but nothing works for me.

[flutter: getting gradle error while running my flutter app for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939423/flutter-getting-gradle-error-while-running-my-flutter-app-for-the-first-time)

In project/android/app/build.Gradle, the GradleException is highlighted in red.

build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

In Console, the error is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.0.6113669. Versions available locally: 20.1.5948944

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 40s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

help me out of this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio is not building flutter app correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092361/android-studio-is-not-building-flutter-app-correctly)

Comment: Yes! but the solutions provided over there is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your NDK through *Project settings -> SDK Location -> Android NDK location*.

If you don't have an NDK, then you need to go to *Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools* Tab, then select NDK (side by side) and install it.